# Check index Resultset

Tags: java, resultset

I'm trying to check if some index exists but I get a sql Exception

```
ResultSet rs = null;
ps = odh.connection().prepareStatement(sql);
rs = ps.executeQuery(); 

 while(rs.next()){
                   String field1 = null;
                   String field2 = null;
                   Timestamp field3 = null;
                   String field4 = null;
                   String field5 = null;

                   if(rs.getString(1) != null)
                       field1 = rs.getString(2);
                   if(rs.getString(2) != null)
                       field2 = rs.getString(3);
                   if(rs.getTimestamp(3)!= null)
                       field3 = rs.getTimestamp(4);
                   if(rs.getString(4) != null)
                      field4 = rs.getString(4);
                   if(rs.getString(5) != null)
                      field5 = rs.getString(5);
                   ....
                   ....
```

and the exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column index is not valid
```

the exception its translated ..

How can I check it?

Comment: can you post the full code please and the exception as well!

Comment: Be more specific, give more details of what is the exception so that others can help you

Comment: Hi newbie, start over there [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then update your question and I am pretty sure, you will get more relevant answers, and maybe also the solution

Comment: I would say your query did not return 4 columns. Also, the increasing numbers look suspicious. What is your SQL query?

Comment: can you show us your query please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
data = rs.getTimestamp(4);
if(rs.wasNull()){ // this tells you if the value that you have fetched is null or not
  // data = {someDefaultValue} 
}
System.out.println(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this statement that cause problem .

```
field5 = rs.getString(6);
```

make sure that you have 6 columns first in selected tables .i think you should start to getString(1) with first column because i don't know why you exactly check column and store next of it ? 
if the answer is not complete ,please provide me with table schema